# Razor Pages as PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, razor-pages

I've been diving into Razor Pages, but also have a need to create PWA apps.  Everything I see about PWAs are related to Blazor.  Can a web application created with Razor Pages be converted to a PWA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know, [C# Razor Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/razor-pages/info) is a **Server Rendering framework(SSR)**, so in any request from browser to server, **html** is returned. This feature is the opposite of PWA (**Client side rendering (CSR)**), in which just the **first** request from browser to server returns html. Consecutive request are performed to the related rest-api or microservice which returns only **json**

So, in Razor, **if you manage to avoid html creation at server layer** (which is the core of server rendering frameworks) and perform the forms creation and other UI tasks with pure javascript (like react, angular, vue, etc) **instead Razor features**, you could convert it to a pwa, adding the classic [manifest](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/blob/master/manifest.json), [service-worker](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/blob/master/service-worker.js) and other required files for a basic pwa application.

If you choose that, you could ask this to your self: ***Why I'm using a backend (c#) framework just to generate a minimal index.html instead of using the powerful Razor features?***

Maybe it is time to move from classic web server frameworks which use server languages (c#, java, python, ruby, etc) to latest javascript frameworks like : react, angular, vue, aurelia, linkstart, etc

Check this resources:

- [Server Rendering vs Client side Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838998/asynchronous-django-ajax-jquery-information/61883353#61883353)

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback. I've been looking into react as well.

Comment: If this was useful, please click the checkmark and/or mark answer as solved :D