# Is it a good practice to keep nodejs server and react frontend in same directory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I need to serve my React built files (build directory) using nodejs server. With React being wrapped in Docker my nodejs server can not access build directory within /frontend. So what I am thinking of is to move my `server.js` into `/frontend` and having a single Dockerfile for both of them.
It would have something like this `CMD ['npm run build', 'node server.js']`

Would that be illegal and bad practice ?

Comment: I certainly could not recommend it, and I don't understand why you would not be able to access the build directory in another folder. Regarding your post, however, "best practices" is outside of the scope of SO as "opinion-based", so please keep away from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To architect a web, you have these options:

## Ancient monoliths

This was the first way to implement a web. All is in the server: frontend & backend. Frontend(html) is created dynamically in the server and sent to the browser on each request.

In this kind of applications:

- only one git repository is required
- develop rest controllers exposing json is not necessary because using html templating, the data is merged to the html. This is called SSR

  - [Replacing Javascript with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69510962/replacing-javascript-with-python/69511019#69511019)
  - [Is Django Asyc Views an ajax replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838998/is-django-asyc-views-an-ajax-replacement/61883353#61883353)
  - [Razor Pages as PWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67696126/razor-pages-as-pwa/67696421#67696421)
- javascript is not required to merge the data into the html

Here some languages and its frameworks

- java: jsp, jsf, thymeleaf, zk, etc
- nodejs : ejs, handlebars
- c# :  razor
- php: wordpress, drupal, etc
- ruby: almost all frameworks
- python: django, flask, etc

Not your case but I saw flows like this:

- a folder called frontend in the git repository with react, angular , vue, etc
- perform the build of this folder : `npm run build`. Usually a human execute this.
- copy the build result (index.html, js, css etc) to another folder called server in the same git repository

## Modern Monoliths

- Similar to the previous explained option but **automated**
- with modern CSR frameworks like: react, angular & vue
- a ton of ready to use features like : login

[image: https://lzomedia.com/blog/different-ways-to-connect-react-frontend-and-node-backend/]

As you can see in the picture, the frontend and backend are deployed n the same server, in the same port.

If your are developing a single site with its backend, it could work to have frontend and backend in the same repository or directory. It will be like the modern monoliths: [mean, mern, mevn](https://www.mongodb.com/mern-stack) with some challenges related to the fact to have different application types in one repository.

## CSR/SPAs with several apis/microservices

[image]

Suitable if:

- The company has a dozens of areas, each with complex requirements, unsolvable with just one web application to the entire company
- web and native mobile version is required with almost the same features
- integrations (request driven & event driven) between the systems are required
- decoupled and modern **authentication** like [IAMs](https://www.esecurityplanet.com/products/best-iam-software/) or with **authorization** flows solvable with [oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/)

**If this is your case**, I advice you a distributed or decoupled architecture. I mean one app or process by repository/server.  Here some advantages :

- frontend (spa) with react

  - own domain like acme.com
  - you could use specialized services for static webs
  - you are not bound to only one api. You could consume several apis.
  - react developers could have its own git strategy
  - custom build for webs
- backend (api) with nodejs

  - own domain like acme.api.com
  - you could scale only the backend because the heavy process is in this layer
  - nodejs developers could have its own git strategy

### serve the spa

If your web is simple, you could use

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-server

But if your web has complexities like backend: env variables portability, one build, etc you could use:

- https://github.com/usil/nodeboot-spa-server

### References

- spa with several apis image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/direct-client-to-microservice-communication-versus-the-api-gateway-pattern
- modern stack monoliths image: https://lzomedia.com/blog/different-ways-to-connect-react-frontend-and-node-backend/

Answer (score 2):

You can't (*) run multiple servers in a single container.

For your setup, though, you don't need multiple servers.  You can compile the React application to static files and serve those from your other application.  There are some more advanced approaches where a server injects the data or a rendered copy of the page as it serves these up; these won't necessarily work with a React dev server in a separate container (probably some of the setup described in [@JRichardsz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71791940) goes into this more).

If both halves are in the same repository, you can potentially use a Docker multi-stage build to compile the front-end application to static files, then copy the result into the main server image.  This could look like:

```sh
# Build the frontend.
FROM node:lts AS frontend
WORKDIR /app
COPY frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY frontend/ ./
RUN npm build
# Built files are left in /app/build; this stage has no CMD.

# Build the main server.
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /app
COPY server/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY server/ ./
# Copy the build tree from the frontend image into this one.
COPY --from=frontend /app/build ./static
RUN npm build

# Normal metadata to set up and run the server container.
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

(*) It's technically possible, but you need to install some sort of process manager, which adds significant complication.  It's less of a concern with the approach I describe here but you also lose some things like the ability to see just a single process's logs or the ability to update only one part of the system without restarting the rest of it.  The `CMD` you suggest won't do it.  I'd almost always use multiple containers over trying to shoehorn in something like supervisord.